# How to make macro with object in function statement?

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply

I'm trying to make macro with object in function statement. Maybe it sounds confusing. I'll try to explain it with code.

I made function statement with code below.

```
ols.fun<-function(x,y){
  middle.fun<-lm(outcome~x1+x2+x3,data=x)
  predict(middle.fun,y)}
```

Object in 'ols.fun', which is x and y, is list with several rows. For example, I made 5 rows with data.frame function.

```
> variable<-data.frame(x=paste0("trainset",1:5), y=paste0("testset",1:5))
> variable
          x        y
1 trainset1 testset1
2 trainset2 testset2
3 trainset3 testset3
4 trainset4 testset4
5 trainset5 testset5
```

I want to put each x, y in ols.fun. I've used lapply like below. However, it didn't worked.

```
> lapply(variable,ols.fun)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'outcome' not found
```

I would really appreciate if you let me know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: It looks like `lm` inside `ols.fun` is expecting to see columns named `outcome`, `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`, but your example data only has columns called `x` and  `y`. I think your error suggests that your real function expects a column called `persureexp`.

Comment: 1. Oh, i made mistake. I edited the all variables names in `ols.fun`. `persurexp`is outcome in `ols.fun`. I corrected it.

2. columns `x`, `y` are data name. data frame 'x' has 'outcome' and `x1`, `x2`, `x3` columns. data frame `y` has `x1`, `x2`, `x3` variables, which will be used in prediction.

Comment: First, use `get(x)` and `get(y)` instead of `x` and `y` in your function. Then use `do.call(mapply, c(list(ols.fun), variable))`.

Comment: And of course, R is an actual programming language and thus doesn't have macros.